# how to fire local notifications on particular days rather than current weekday

Tags: ios, swift3, uilocalnotification

I'm working on an Alarm app. While setting up the alarm, user selects days which are getting stored in an array. But I'm not getting correct weekday when trying to place the value while making notification. In my code I'm getting weekdays in "daysValue" ([0,1,1,1,0,0,0], means alarm is set for monday, tuesday and wednesday) but I'm getting no clue how to pass these values in trigger date. Here's the code

```
var daysValue: [Int]
        daysValue = AlarmController.shared.days

        print(daysValue)
        for _ in daysValue
        {
            for ind in 0...countNum
            {
                guard let fireDate = alarm.fireDate else { return }
                print(fireDate)
                let date = fireDate.addingTimeInterval((1.0*Double(ind)) * 60.0)
                print(date)
                let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: date)
                print(weekday)



                let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        print(triggerDate)
                        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: true)
                        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(alarm.uuid)\(ind)", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
                        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
                        {
                            (error) in
                            if let error = error
                            {
                                print("Unable to add notification request, \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                    }

            }

        }
```